# python running python2 instead of python3 on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

for i in range(15):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

when I run it like this in command prompt:

```
prog1.py
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\Ja\Desktop>prog1.py
File "C:\Users\Ja\Desktop\prog1.py", line 4
print(i, end=' ')
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but when I run it like this:

```
py prog1.py
```

it works fine. It's running python2.7.15 instead of python3.6.5 (I tested it using sys.version).
( It's the same for icon clicks )

Comment: This is very difficult to assess without knowing more about your machine. Can you post your PythonPath environment variable and the result of `sys.path` from inside a Python script?

Comment: sys.path: ['C:\\Users\\Ja\\Desktop', 'C:\\Users\\Ja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Ja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Ja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Ja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32', 'C:\\Users\\Ja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: This is my path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;

Comment: Add `path` in your **path variable** where `python.exe` file is located. Like mine is located in `C:\Anaconda3`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be under the impression that Windows understands the "shebang line":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

It does not.  All Windows knows is that .py files can be run by Python.  So you need to update your file association, or run the correct version of Python explicitly, passing the path to your script as an argument.

Comment: @Igracx33: Rather than "link and run" would you like to tell us something specific?